# Grails domain class

Tags: grails, types, dns, character

I have defined the following domain class:

```
class Content {

  Map i18nDescription = [:]
  ...

}
```

If run the following code

```
content.i18nDescription['it'] = "desc desc...."
content.save()
```

I get the following error:

```
util.JDBCExceptionReporter ERROR: value too long for type character varying(255)
```

(I'm using postgres as database)

How can I increase the size of the field `i18nDescription['it']` in the database using

```
static constraints = {}
```

thanks

Comment: Is [this SO answer with solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237393/how-to-adjust-constraints-db-mapping-for-map-within-grails-domain-class) acceptable for you ?

Answer (score 0):

```
static mapping = {
        title i18nDescription: "text"
    }
```

That will create a text field. Which has more than 4000 characters.

Comment: But in this my field is not a map anymore. I want a map since I use it to store the same text in different language

Comment: Ah you can't store a map in just one field. You have to create a separate table that contains these fields : content_id, key, value

Comment: You could break the map down into a string representation (which is what grails appears to be doing anyway) and save/load it as a text block. You'll need to create helper get/set methods to do this parsing, I think. Either way, you're not storing a 'map' in the database, just a String representation of it.