# Grails: How to put a minSize constraints on map

Tags: validation, grails, dictionary, grails-2.2

I have this object

```
@Validateable
class Foo {
    Map<String, String> items

    static constraints = {
        items minSize: 1
    }
}
```

but this test fail:

```
@Test
void shouldNotValidateIfItemsIsEmpty() {
    Foo foo = new Foo(items: [:])

    assert !foo.validate()
}
```

What do I do wrong? It's supposed to work according to [grails 'minSize' documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.0/ref/Constraints/minSize.html): "Sets the minimum size of a **collection** or number property."

Comment: Just to check if this is a constraint problem or the object isn't validated: what happens if you add another non nullable field?

Comment: If I add the constrains "nullable: true" to "items" and I do the same test with a "items: null", the validation fail with the code "nullable"

Comment: grails has issues with `Map` properties and constraints. See [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237393/how-to-adjust-constraints-db-mapping-for-map-within-grails-domain-class)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation might be misleading. The minSize constraint will only apply to:

1. String
2. Arrays
3. Classes which implements the java.util.Collection interface

[java.util.Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) however does not extend the [java.util.Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) interface

See the `supports` method of `MinSizeConstraint`:

```
public boolean supports(Class type) {
        return type != null && (
                String.class.isAssignableFrom(type) ||
                Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(type) ||
                type.isArray());
    }
```

You can develop your own [custom constraint](http://blog.andresteingress.com/2010/03/19/creating-custom-constraints/) for this or a custom validator as suggested by Thermech

In addition, in order for Grails to mock the validate method properly your test class should be something like:

```
@TestMixin(ControllerUnitTestMixin) class FooTest {
    @Test
    void shouldNotValidateIfItemsIsEmpty() {
        Foo foo = mockCommandObject Foo

        foo.items = [:]

        assert !foo.validate()
    } }
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way I found, is with a custom validator:

```
static constraints = {
    items validator:  { Map map, obj, errors ->
        if (map.size() < 1) errors.rejectValue('items', 'minSize.notmet')
    }
}
```